# IndexOutOfBoundsException when migrating from Java6 to Java8

Tags: primefaces, indexoutofboundsexception, jsf-2.2

We are currently migrating our application from Java6 to Java8.We use primefaces-4.0 and JSF 2.2 version.

Following is the code:

```
// Iterate over columns.
                for (int i = 0; i < dynamicList.get(0).size(); i++) {
                    // Create <h:column>.
                    column = new Column();
                    // Create <h:outputText value="dynamicHeaders[i]"> for <f:facet name="header"> of column.
                    column.setHeaderText(dynamicHeaders[i]);
                    //column.setWidth("" + (100 / dynamicHeaders.length));
                    //dynamicDataTable.getChildren().add(column);
                    System.out.println("Table after setting values");
                    System.out.println("List size is:"+dynamicList.size());
                    System.out.println("First list size is:"+dynamicList.get(0).size());
                    System.out.println("Elements:"+dynamicList.get(0)); 
                    System.out.println(column.getHeaderText());
                    System.out.println(column.getChildren().get(i)); //Getting IndexOutOfBounds exception in this line
                    // Create <h:outputText value="#{dynamicItem[" + i + "]}"> for the body of column.
                    output = new OutputLabel();
                    output.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{dynamicItem[" + i + "]}", String.class));
                    column.getChildren().add(output);
                    System.out.println("Column information");
                    System.out.println(output.toString());
                    System.out.println(output.getValue());
                    System.out.println(output.getChildren().get(i));
                    System.out.println(output.getValueExpression("value"));
                    System.out.println(output.getChildren().size());
                    System.out.println(output.getFamily());
                    
                }
```

We are generating reports in Excel. When debugging code able to see IndexOutOfBounds Exception(have commented the line). In logs I'm able to print the list values and table is also constructed using primefaces. I'm facing issue only when setting value to the table.This works fine in Java6.

I'm unable to identify where the issue is.Kindly help.

Comment: Following is the exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:670)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:446)
        at javax.faces.component._ComponentChildrenList.get(_ComponentChildrenList.java:43)
        at javax.faces.component._ComponentChildrenList.get(_ComponentChildrenList.java:29)

Comment: I am not positive but you are creating `new Column()` and then asking for its `getChildren().get(0)` it doesn't have any children yet and you are asking for the first one in the list.  I don't see how this worked in Java 6 vs 8 this looks like a fundamental problem.